# DJANGO MODELS, use one class objects in another class (ManyToManyField) (?)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I want to use one class object inside another class.

What I want to achieve: 
I have already created some Ingredient objects like 'chicken', 'rice' and so on.
Every with its own calories, proteins, etc.
Now I want to create a Meal from those Ingredients and calculate calories summary.

**My goals**:
1. Create meal: 
sample_dinner = Meal(name='sample_dinner',ing1='chicken',ing2='rise',ing3='tomato')
2. Calculate calories, function is easy to write but I need to pass args first
3. Show them in view (I have know how)

**models.py**

```py
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,default='')
    calories = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    proteins = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    carbs = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    fat = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    ingredientone = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

    calories_value = calc_nut_value()

    def calc_nut_value():
        ingr1 = Ingredient.objects.get(name=(f.e 'chicken'))
        ingr2 = Ingredient.objects.get(name=(f.e 'rice'))
        ingr3 = Ingredient.objects.get(name=(f.e 'tomato'))
        calories = ingr1.calories + ingr2.calories + ingr3.calories 
        return calories
```

Comment: Why do you want pass argument? It makes more sense compute calories value from all ingredients instead chicken only

Comment: I have full table of Ingredients, not only for this particular meal but for all I'll create in the future. f.e. I don't want to put chicken in my cereals for breakfast... So I want only chosen ones

Comment: But if you want calculate calories for chicken why you have calories_value in Meal model. It should be in Ingredient class. I don't understand it, you havea class Meal (one meal can have a lot of ingredients) and you calculate calories_value in this class for only one ingredient?

Comment: I have just edited code to be more clear.

Comment: And all ingredients in calc_nut_value are related to specific meal? Because you don't need to choose specific ingredients, you can choose all ingredients related to specific meal. It makes sense to me

Comment: Yeah, but how to relate those 3 to that particular meal? (Sorry, I'm complete newbie)

Comment: E.g. You have a meal "chicken with tomato and rice". Ingredients are chicken, tomato and rice and you want calculate to calories_value attribute of calories from all of ingredients to "chicken with tomato and rice". No problem man. I understand that it is not so easy.

Comment: I understand your point but how to code it? How to choose only 3 ingredients?

Comment: I edited my answer. I am really sorry, I've made a mistake. Now the code in the answer should work, I tried the code in own project with your model. Let me know if the code works. I gave you an upvote because you put a lot of effort to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer was much more harder than I said. I am really sorry for that. It is because [ManyToMany relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) is saved outside of save method and you can't calculate value in overrided save method because we can't get ingredients there. I tested my code on your model and it works. But you have to create [signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signals/).

M2M_changed signal is called everytime ManyToMany relation is created or changed. In this signal you can calculate values from ManyToMany relation. You can get relation via parameter from your model.

First you have to create signal in signals.py file:

```
from .models import Meal
from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed
from django.dispatch import receiver


@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Meal.ingredientone.through)
def calc_calories(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    # you can get all ingredients for meal
    ingrs = instance.ingredientone.all()

    # iterate over ingredients
    calories = 0
    for ingr in ingrs:
        calories += ingr.calories
    instance.calories_value = calories
    instance.save()
```

Then you have to import your signals in apps.py (in AppConfig). This config you have to use in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py but I think in newer version of Django this is a standard way:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AppNameConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'appname'

    def ready(self):
        import appname.signals
```

This code works nicely, if you will have any other problems. Please don't hesitate and ask me.